# Saving predicted tensor to image in TensorFlow - Graph finalized

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was able to train a model in TensorFlow with my own data. Input and Output of the model are images. I now tried to get the output of the predictions and save it to an png image file to see what's going on. Unfortunately I am getting an error when running the following function I created to test with predictions. My goal is to save the prediction that is also an image so I can open it with a normal image viewer.

Some more to the code. In my main I am creating an estimator

```
def predict_element(my_model, features):
  eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x=features,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False)

  eval_results = my_model.predict(input_fn=eval_input_fn)

  predictions = eval_results.next() #this returns a dict with my tensors
  prediction_tensor = predictions["y"] #get the tensor from the dict
  
  image_tensor = tf.reshape(prediction_tensor, [IMG_WIDTH, -1]) #reshape to a matrix due my returned tensor is a 1D flat one
  decoded_image = tf.image.encode_png(image_tensor)
  write_image = tf.write_file("output/my_output_image.png", decoded_image)
  
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(write_image))

def get_input():
  filename_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("features/*.png")
  label_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("labels/*.png")

  # Make a Dataset of image tensors by reading and decoding the files.
  image_dataset = filename_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.cast(tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file(x), channels=1),tf.float32))
  l_dataset = label_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.cast(tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file(x),channels=1),tf.float32))

  image_reshape = image_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.reshape(x, [IM_WIDTH * IM_HEIGHT]))
  label_reshape = l_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.reshape(x, [IM_WIDTH * IM_HEIGHT]))

  iterator = image_reshape.make_one_shot_iterator()
  iterator2 = label_reshape.make_one_shot_iterator()

  next_img = iterator.get_next()
  next_lbl = iterator2.get_next()

  features = []
  labels = []
  # read all 10 images and labels and put it in the array
  # so we can pass it to the estimator
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(10):
      t1, t2 = sess.run([next_img, next_lbl])
      features.append(t1)
      labels.append(t2)

  return {"x": np.array(features)}, np.array(labels)

def main(unused_argv):
    features, labels = get_input() # creating the features dict {"x": }
    my_estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=my_cnn_model, model_dir="/tmp/my_model")

    predict_element(my_estimator, features)
```

The error is

> Graph is finalized and cannot be modified

With some easy print() statements I could see that retrieving the dict with

> eval_results = my_model.predict(input_fn=eval_input_fn)

is probable the one which finalizes the graph.
I absolutely don't know what to do or where to look for a solution here. How could I save the output?

I tried this in my model_fn:

```
#the last layer of my network is dropout
predictions = {
   "y": dropout
    }

  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    reshape1 = tf.reshape(dropout, [-1,IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT])
    sliced = tf.slice(reshape1, [0,0,0], [1, IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT])
    encoded = tf.image.encode_png(tf.cast(sliced, dtype=tf.uint8))
    outputfile = tf.write_file(params["output_path"], encoded)
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)
```

My problem here is that I can't pass back the "outputfile" node so I can work with it.

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: `Graph is finalized and cannot be modified` is the error that stops me from using my predicitons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for everyone with the same problem here is my solution. I don't know if this is the proper way but it works.

In my predict function i created a second graph for the reshaping, slicing, encoding and saving like:

```
  pred_dict = eval_results.next() #generator the predict function returns
  preds = pred_dict["y"] #get the predictions from the dict

  #create the second graph
  g = tf.Graph()
  with g.as_default():
    inp = tf.Variable(preds)
    reshape1 = tf.reshape(printnode, [IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT, -1])
    sliced = tf.slice(reshape1, [0,0,0], [ IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT,1])
    reshaped = tf.reshape(sliced, [IM_HEIGHT, IM_WIDTH, 1])
    encoded = tf.image.encode_png(tf.image.convert_image_dtype(reshaped,tf.uint16))
    outputfile = tf.write_file("/tmp/pred_output/prediction_img.png", encoded)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
      sess.run(outputfile)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well your graph is finalized and cannot be modified. You can either add this tensorflow operations to your model (before running it) or simply write some python code which saves the images seperately (without using tensorflow). Maybe I'll find some old code of mine as an example.

You could also create a second graph, then you can use tensorflow without changing the existing model graph.

You have to distinguish between graph nodes and evaluated objects. tf.reshape doesn't take an array as input but a graph node.
https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graphs

Comment: But where do i have to add this operations. In my model_fn? The feature dict i am passing to the predict function has a batch of 10 images thus i am getting back 10 predictions. How to save them as single images? I am not able to use the slice functions to obtain single predicted tensors?!

Comment: First question: Yes, if you want to use the tensorflow graph operations add them in the estimator model/graph definiton. I did this during training once.
However when you recieve the dictionary you should be able to reduce it to single arrays and then save it as image e.g. with PyPNG

Comment: i added what i tried in the question post. could you have a look at it?

Comment: As far as I can see, your prediction output is unchanged. In addition, the Tensorflow graph now saves the images as png files. This should solve your problem, as indicated in your second sentence in your original question.

Comment: Yeah the prediction dict is unchaged because of the fact i cannot extend it. Tensorflow is counting the entrys and has thrown an error at me when i put some more in there. But anyway, i now managed to get what i wanted by implementing a second graph for reshaping, encoding and saving the predictions. Thank you very much for your help :)